# How to add an extra custom block to dashboard in magento 2?

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.3.2, dashboard

I want to show some new custom block in magento admin dashboard as well as want to remove some existing unwanted blocks?

How can i do this?

Comment: Which block you want to remove from dashboard ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya i want to remove entire existing blocks and want to add my own custom block which have some custom tables reporting.

Comment: Means you want to remove existing blocks which is available on dashboard and you need to add all custom blocks ?

Comment: yes exactly that's what i want?

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: Sure thank you. I will check and update your.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How to add new custom block on admin dashboard Magento 2?**

You can add this file in your custom module here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_dashboard_index.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_block" template="Vendor_Module::test.phtml" before="-" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now you need to create one `phtml` file here at this location

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/test.phtml

Content for this file is..

```
<?php echo "Custom Block"; ?>
```

**How to remove default Magento blocks from dashboard ?**

You need to add below lines in your `XML` file `adminhtml_dashboard_index.xml` inside `<body>` tags.

```
<referenceBlock name="dashboard" remove="true" />
<referenceBlock name="analytics_service_external_link" remove="true" />
```

**Output :**

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you, its worked for me, I will build my requirement on that.

Comment: Great! Happy Coding. +1 for acceptance! :)